# Slow Performance on Scaled PHP/MySQL Application on Openshift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I have two scaled PHP installations on Openshift using Small Gears (1 for PHP, 1 for MySQL per application so 4 small gears all together) and both installations are extremely slow, and only occasionally bearable. I've seen a lot of questions about this that say to disable functionality (like Wordpress Plugins for example), but my application has worked SUPER fast on shared hosting using the current feature-set and can't exist without the features currently in use.

My hope in using Openshift was to avoid having to do server config and have an instantly scalable platform. So my question is what needs to be done to get this config up to speed so I can continue using Openshift? Or is it not possible without the same amount of time and energy it would take me to just setup my own AWS resources?

Should I be using Medium or Large Gears for my application to have the speed necessary to run a real-world application (even though there's only one user)?

For additional information:

- I am currently the only user (no one else is accessing the site).
- I frequently get HTTP 503 errors (after refreshing a few times these go away)
- Using ssh and looking at the gear's resources I never come close to pegging the CPU and am always within the 20%-50% threshold on the CPU.
- Memory usage is reporting 7416848k used of 7513696k available with the httpd processes taking a total of 1% of memory
- I have done 0 customization, all I did was start the app with php 5.4 and MySQL (scaled) and did a git push of my code.

Comment: Couple questions... Do the applications ever scale (does app A go to 3 or 4 gears) If so, is the performance any better? Also what does your application primarily do? This lets us understand your use case a bit better an provide a targeted solution.

Comment: @niharvey The application never scales. The application is a custom Wordpress setup and mostly does things other Wordpress sites do (serve HTML to browsers), all media assets are offloaded to S3.

Comment: @niharvey Is it possible that this could be a result of the database being slow? What's the typical latency between a scaled application and the database gear? Should I be using a Medium Gear for MySQL or something like Amazon RDS?

Comment: Its certainly possible that the database being on a small gear can cause performance issues. You can try using larger gears or using something like RDS to see if speeds things up.